# Dwellers return automatically after finding a low amount of items in Wasteland

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have a strange thing happening - dwellers I send to explore wasteland are automatically returning to vault after finding a little amount of items (4 or 5).

The exploration log says: "That's as much as I can carry. I better head back and show the Overseer what I found".

Before today they successfully carried up to 30 items and never returned to vault on their own.

I don't know is it relevant or not, but I have a lot of free storage space available.

What caused this change?
What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Cannot confirm for now, sent two dwellers exploring and one of them already has 5 items (the other one - 3) and it looks like they are not planning to stop exploring right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed for me when update with the the valentine day sale arrived. Now dwellers can carry as much as they could before.

Comment: I sent dwellers out yesterday and they just returned today. again with 3-5 items each. So did I missunderstand you, or shouldn't that have happened?

Comment: I checked just now, everything is still working for me. If someone will provide better answer, which may help others, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: When did the valentinesday patch apply? and since when it seems to be solving?

Comment: At February 12th valentine day sale began, at February 15th it was ended. This problem was solved for me when sale started.