# When does "The wasteland dwellers can't carry anymore" occur?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I read about a problem and that it got fixed with the Valentine's day update.

But I'm actually interested in when this event is supposed to happen. My intention to ask this is because It's still occurring in pretty inconsistent manners even after the past Valentine's-patch (so it's presumably not caused by a bug).

Just today one started to return after 2 days and 22hours. While it's true that the amount of items out of the wastelands exceeds my storage rooms, There is anyway another dweller out for more than 6 days with even more items counted and still going on...

I prepared for like 6 months a set of SPECIAL maxed dwellers with damage resistance pets and weapons in dmg ranges between 19 and 22. Now I finally reached the point and started raiding the wastelands, all my top dwellers return randomly with no obvisious reasons by complaining about an full inventory...

I see no pattern in this. **What are the reasons for a dweller to decide that he has too much stuff and return?** And how can I prevent this?

Comment: Asking how it happens or what the devs were expecting is off-topic.  Asking why they come back is a [dupe](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255257/dwellers-return-automatically-after-finding-a-low-amount-of-items-in-wasteland); that's already been asked.

Comment: @Frank: I'm not asking what the devs were expecting. And I disaggree it beeing a dupe, since I'm asking of "when it is expected to happen?" Where actually "There is no scenario where it is expected to happen" would be a valid answer. What is different from "This happened due to a bug"

Comment: Are you asking when an event will happen, then?  I'm having trouble figuring out what, exactly, you're asking.

Comment: @Frank I'm asking when the carrying to much event is intended to trigger. so looking for an answer like "Usually when your dweller has more than X items" or "After y days it will happen" or as commented allready "Actually there is nothing expected to provoke this"

Comment: So your question is "how many items is too many items normally"? I've not personally hit an upper limit yet, but if that's your question, an edit to your question above would be in order. You would likely get a much faster response.

Answer (score 3):

After much testing and counting out how many items my dwellers come back with, the limit for how much they can hold before they turn back is 100.

Comment: As far as I know (and consistent with my experience), this is the answer. Also note that with the latest update, junk does count against the 100 item limit, but recipes do not.

Comment: The 100 item limit has thoroughly been proved at www.steamcommunity.com